# Error in creating a map file using Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express(Free version)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, file, dictionary

When I try to create a map file for a workspace that I have in MS-VS C++ 2010 Express, by giving the option in Project Settings-->Linker-->Debugging-->Generate Map file = Yes(/MAP command line linker option) and its name there, and build again I keep getting an error saying:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file proj.map

File seems to be created but with zero size and no contents in it.

Any pointers to resolve this?

Doesn't the Free version of the tool allow to generate a map file?

Are there any Quick (w/o having to add some debug code..) ways using VS-C++ 2010 Express/Some other tool to count:

1. Code size of functions I have (C code).
2. Stack memory used by particular function.
3. Heap memory used by the same function.
4. Cycles consumed by this C/C++ code.

Comment: @leppie: Checked file/folder permissions. No issue there.

Comment: Perhaps there are limitations? Try a simple program from the command line.

Answer (score 3):

make  project property increamental linking option under linker-> general to "NO/incremental"
wil solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Visual Studio 2010, which MS have fixed in 2012, however they did not release a HF for this as the workaround of disabling incremental link works.

Answer (score 0):

`Superb Linker-> general` to "`NO/incremental`" resolved my below problem:

1. Some times the map file is generated with 0 size
2. Other times the map file is partially generated and couldn't be opened